# Gamma function limit to integral question

Tags: gamma-function

I am reading up on the gamma function and have seen a formula that I can't connect to the usual integral definition. Namely,

$$
\Gamma(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n!n^{x-1}}{x(x+1)\cdots(x+n-1)}, \qquad x\neq 0,-1,-2,\dots 
$$

How can I connect this formula with the standard definition:

$$
\Gamma(x) = \int^\infty_0 t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt
$$

Comment: This is standard text book material. Any book that deals with Gamma function in detail has a proof.

Comment: This can be shown using the factorization of $\frac 1{\Gamma(z)}$, which can be derived from the functional equation $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}$.